# Get Revit model tree, family information and attributes in .NET backend application

Tags: c#, .net, backend, autodesk-forge

I know you can get the model tree for a Revit file with a javascript viewer.

Example of this is: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/viewer

But I want to access all the data of a Revit file (model tree, families, ...) in a .NET backend application.

What is the best and easiest way to do that without using a viewer?

Comment: you can use Model Derivative API to fetch model data on the cloud without viewer. this blog might be helpful :https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer